# closed form of a series

Tags: sequences-and-series

For any real values $a,b>1$, let $s_i = a^i\cdot\left( \frac{1}{b} \right)^{2^i}$ for all $i=0,1,\ldots$. Then is there a closed form of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} s_i$? and why? (you may assume $a<b$ or the other way to show the existence of closed form.)

If there is no closed form, then is it possible to get a tight upper bound?

Comment: No, there is no simpler way to write $\sum_{n=0}^\infty  z^{2^n}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any reason why? and is it possible to have a tight upper bound?

Comment: The short answer to the first question is "because the unit circle is the natural boundary and every elementary (in the classical sense) function can be analytically continued along almost every ray".

Comment: Although they are not "named" special functions, series such as these are well-studied.  The phrase to look up is "lacunary series".